# How to send extra field data to the backend using Uploadify 3.0?

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

Has anyone used Uploadify version 3.0 beta? I am having difficulty to implement it. There is no documentation available at the moment. If someone has used the script please let me know how to send extra fields data to the backend php file. Here's what I'm trying (and doesnt work) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
    "swf"  : "uploadify.swf",
    "uploader"    : "uploadify.php",
    "cancelImage" : "uploadify-cancel.png",
    "auto"      : true, 
    "onUploadStart" : function(){
        $("#file_upload").uploadifySettings("postData",{
                    "name": $("#name").val(),                    
                     },0);
        },

        })
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <form id="upload_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="1" /><br />
    choose file:<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
    <div id="recordHolder" style="display:none"></div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
'onUploadStart' : function(){
$('#mugshot_upload_new').uploadifySettings(
    'postData', 
    {
        "name": $("#name").val(),
        "userId": $("#userId").val()
    }
);
},
```

without "0" at the end. It works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3 , This worked with me

```
'onUploadStart' : function() {                                                      
    $("#file_upload_1").uploadify("settings", 'formData',{"user_email_input": $("#user_email_input").val()})
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correct, to retrieve extra fields just add them in the onUpload function; this should work (there are no other fields I see there)

```
"onUploadStart" : function(){
        $("#file_upload").uploadifySettings("postData",{
                    "name": $("#name").val(),
                    "userId": $("#userId").val(),
                    },0);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply. As you see in my code, Im doing same, however I cant get any variable on 'uploadify.php' file. is my config above correct? and how can I get the posted variables on the php file? Thanks.

Comment: @adam I saw you missed one field in your js call (userID). To get the fields in PHP just use the $_POST array in your file uploadify.php, as you would normally do